# Linux PPTX presentation Viewer

Tags: debian, libreoffice, openoffice, documents

Besides Open Office, is there any solution for opening `.pptx` presentations on Linux (Debian to be more precise)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Other than [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/), you could use an online conversion tool like [Google docs](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186466) to convert presentations from `.pptx` either directly or via a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-docs-viewer-pdf-doc-doc/). There are other online conversion tools like [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) to convert the `.pptx` to a format that you can access on your machine; format choices include:

- `.html`
- `.pdf`
- `.odp`
- `.png`

Comment: Today, just use LibreOffice 5.

Comment: @Masi Yes: that is literally the first thing I said in my answer...

Answer (score 4):

Stage (the presentations component) of [Calligra](http://www.calligra.org/) is able to open .pptx files.

Answer (score 4):

*Kingsoft Office 2013*

This is sort of the Chinese version of Microsoft Office, but with support for English and a few other languages, and has be simply brilliant in the latest versions. It has a nice interface compared to the bog standard libreoffice - **and versions later than the `4207` 2013 version can edit Office 2010 .docx documents, as well as pptx and Excel formats**.

It is available as a one-install package, which provides versions of Word, Presentation/Powerpoint, and Calc/Excel. For most uses, Libreoffice will workgreat, but this is sometimes necessary for compatibility with unimplemented pieces of M$ Office formatting.

[image: Kingsoft Word]

**<del>I will also note that any North Americans who may want to use this may have a problem, due to licensing things - https://askubuntu.com/a/235960/178596</del> EDIT: this may not the case anymore**

> **As of 2013:**
>   Be sure to read their
>   restrictions: AMERICANS downloading it are violating their license and
>   confirm they may be sued. http://wps.cn/privacy/unixdistribute
>   "Kingsoft authorizes you the non-exclusive right to use the "Product" in the
>   territorial scope in the world (“Authorized Territorial Scope”) except
>   for North America (including only the United States, Canada and
>   Greenland, similarly hereinafter)"
>   *Credit to @Rinzwind*

You can download the installation DEB or RPM files from here:
http://wps-community.org/downloads

There is a guide to installing .deb files here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-how-do-i-install-deb-packages/

For rpm's, you can `cd` to the directory where it has been downloaded, then `sudo yum install PACKAGE-NAME.rpm` for Fedora and other rpm systems.

For both this AND libreoffice, you may get better compatibility if you can get the Windows fonts and install them onto your Ubuntu computer. You can copy them from the `fonts` directory on a Windows computer on its `C:` drive.

When using it you can change the interface etc from toolbar style to ribbon style. Also may I suggest saving in a format other than the default (e.g. `docx` or `odt` if possible), it makes it much easier if you don't have installed elsewhere as its format not supported that widely.

**Please note this usually can be found as FREEWARE, not freely or open source. You will almost definitely want to consult the Terms & Conditions, and Privacy Policy (possibly [this one](http://www.wps.cn/privacy/unixdistribute/)) before installing.**

Comment: the North American clause is no longer in the privacy/distribute statement.

Comment: The .deb version has been down now four months. They promised to push a new version soon on February. Let's hope it happens soon.

Comment: The software is now called WPS office. There is an alpha release, about two months old. It can render correctly many .ppt files which LibreOffice cannot. It is much more stable than the previous versions, also with big files >100 Mb. - - Please, update your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given a subscription of Microsoft Office, you can also view/edit Office files online at: https://www.office.com

Answer (score 0):

If you need to edit important pptx files that you share with others the only valid solution as of today  is to run MS Office a virtual machine. For example using Virtual Box which is easy to set up and responsive. If you want to read pptx then Libreoffice is great, as well as  many of the other proposed alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

the Free WPS Office for Linux which can not only edit and view ppt presentation files but also can edit word and excel.

you can visit it [here](https://linux.wps.com/)